# Method not working, no compiler errors

Tags: java, methods

I'm sorry for this question because I know it's really simple, but I'm used to python and js, so java is very new to me and I haven't found anything telling me why this isn't working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

     }

    public static double changeToFahrenheit(){

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-20: ");
        double celsius = reader.nextInt();
        double fahrenheit = (9/5) * celsius +32;

        System.out.println(fahrenheit);
        return fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

When I run this I get `"sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld"`

I'm using the codinggrounds Java compiler and executer, I would like for it to ask for a number and then convert it to fahrenheit upon user input

Comment: Among many other things, `9/5` is integer division and will just give you 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually call `changeToFahrenheit` from your main method, so your code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
          changeToFahrenheit();
     }

    public static double changeToFahrenheit(){

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0-20: ");
        double celsius = reader.nextInt();
        double fahrenheit = (9/5) * celsius +32;

        System.out.println(fahrenheit);
        return fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

To use a function, you must call a function (This is like the equivalent of the `Main` function in C#). By the way, you cannot do `9/5`, since integer division will result in an integer, `1`. Try `9.0/5.0` for the computation.

Comment: Or just multiply by `celsius` before dividing.

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling `changeToFahrenheit()` method from `main()` method, so it will do nothing and exit

Comment: thank you that makes it run, I've done a little C# but didn't really know what the Java main() was for and everything online just has it there naturally but doesn't say why.
Can you tell me if there is a problem with my celsius variable. When I enter a number I don't get the right fahrenheit conversion. For example I entered 10 and got 42 but it should've been 50

Comment: thanks I fixed it @chrylis kind of annoying to need to put 9.0 instead of 9 though

Answer (score 0):

- As the method is static method you could call the method with out creating an object.
- reader.nextInt(); // This returns integer .. so store it in integer.
- you don't have to return value unless you have other methods which reuses this value returned.